# How to use Column indexed in parquet to filter out rows before reading into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Parquet has had [Column Indexes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1201) since 2018, however I can't seem to find any package that has exploited Parquet's column index to filter out rows and only load rows that satisfy some condition (or predicate) into pandas?

Is there a way to "exploit" the parquet column indexes? In `pandas.read_parquet(..., index_columns = [value1, value2])` etc?

Answer (score 1):

The column index feature was implemented in 2018 but has not been released yet. In the JIRA you linked, you can see that the fix version is set to 1.11.0, but as of Oct 2019, [the latest release is 1.10.1](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.parquet%20AND%20a:parquet&core=gav).

Answer (score 0):

Tracking issue for the C++ implementation (which pandas uses through pyarrow) is here: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/26168

As of mid-2023 it is still able to only read the index data structures but not actually make use of them.

The Java implementation was released on 2019-11-13 with parquet-mr 1.11.0